# Spring Injection getting null pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring

I get a null pointer exception when trying to inject an object. Here is my code:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
 </context-param>'
```

ApplicationContext.XML

```
<bean id="accessDao" 
 Class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" 
  autowire-candidate="true">
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />   
  <property name="target" ref="accessDaoTarget" />   
   <property name="transactionAttributes">   
   <props>   
  <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>   
   </props>   
  </property>   

</bean>   '
```

CommonBean

```
import com.domain.dao.IDao;
@Named
public class CommonBean implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private IDao accessDao;


public IDao getAccessDao()

      {
        return accessDao;
      }

 public void setAccessDao(IDao accessDao)
  {
    this.accessDao = accessDao;
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have "context:component-scan" defined in your applicationContext.xml context file.

Comment: s..Here it is <context:component-scan base-package="com.myjsf.appl.CommonBean" />

Comment: Have you tried with `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`?

Comment: Hi..I tried..but no use..

Answer (score 0):

The reason i suppose is because the component scan should include all the files that annotated by Spring.
So for this to work , broaden the scope of packages to scan.

change from

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myjsf.appl.CommonBean" />
```

to

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.domain,com.myjsf" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediately reply Mr.sudhakar..I tried it but still getting the same exception

Comment: Hi mohan he s referring two different packages seperated by comma.

Comment: Can you make sure you add all packages that use spring annotation to the <context:component-scan> tag, also can you post your applicationContext.xml and your package structure

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason is because you are refering to an "accessDao" bean which implements a IDAO interface. 
The bean accessDao declared on applicationContext.xml is of type org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean which implements the BeanFactoryAware interface and NOT the IDAO interface.

As so spring will not recognize the bean you are trying to inject (IDAO accessDAO)
and your property will not be initialized.

Comment: Wrong. That bean will implement interfaces defined by the `target` specified.